# Android studio layout background error

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="com.example.black.myfirstproject.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> android:background="@drawable/background"

i wanted background in MainActivity so added background and clicked "Run" 
-> app is down

why my app is down?

// before added background.png in res ->drawable folder

Comment: What do you mean "my app is down" ??

Comment: @JesseBuss "Unfortunately,app has stopped"

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that comes along with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an ImageView - Caution: there are serious memory implications if large images aren't loaded correctly.

You should also read: [Displaying Bitmaps Effectively](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.black.myfirstproject.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also refer to:
android:scaleType=""

for options on positioning the image and specifying how it is displayed within the ImageView.